# JPA MEMBER OF with PATTERN

Tags: jpa

In JPA, Can I use *pattern_value* with **MEMBER OF**?

```sql
WHERE '%abc_' MEMBER OF e.keywords
```

Here comes quote from the SPEC and I don't think it's written in English. :)

```
collection_member_expression ::=
    entity_or_value_expression [NOT] MEMBER [OF] collection_valued_path_expression
entity_or_value_expression ::=
    single_valued_object_path_expression |
    state_field_path_expression |
    simple_entity_or_value_expression
simple_entity_or_value_expression ::=
    identification_variable |
    input_parameter |
    literal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEMBER OF is kind of old JPQL syntax, I would just use JOINs or sub-selects as they are more clear.

```
Select e from Employee e join e.keywords k where k like '%abc'
```